# how can i create a class inside a loop

Tags: python

## Experiment

```py
class calculator:
    class add:
        def __init__(self,*arg):
            self.arg = arg
            
        def display_new(self):
            return sum(self.arg)
            
    class multiply:
        def __init__(self,*arg):
            self.arg = arg
        
        
        class multi_num:
            def __init__(self,*arg):
                self.arg = arg
            
            def nature(self):
                sum = 1
                for x in arg:
                    sum=sum*x
                return sum
      
    class devide:
        def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            
        def display3(self):
            try:
                result = self.x/self.y
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print("error: divided by zero")
            else:
                return (result)
            
calc = calculator()

     multiply = calc.multiply(1,2,3,4,5)
     multiply.display2()
```

its not displaying the result. how can I fix this and where am I making mistake ,add and divide is working properly but I don't know why this multiply is not working.

Comment: I hope this is part of a weird academical task because stacking classes like this is not how you would write a program.

Comment: do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `not working.` is the most useless information. You have to describe it. If you get wrong result then show what you get and what you expect. And do it in question, not in comment. And don't expect that we will run code to see your problems. Besides code may works correctly on our computers.

Answer (score 0):

Change `arg` to `self.arg`:

```
def nature(self):
    sum = 1
    for x in self.arg:
        sum=sum*x
    return sum
```